# Integration with a Max Function as integrand - Application to Covariance

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, covariance

I am having trouble understanding what happens mathematically when a max function is being integrated and for that reason I cannot understand what is happening in the worked examples that are demonstrating this process. Here is the worked example in question:

I have the following functions relating to the estimated remaining lifetimes of 2 machine parts A and B. The remaining lifetime of both parts $\sim U[0,40]$. The policy pays when either part A breaks down or both A and B break down. The problem asks for the covariance of the payment times.  I will include parts of the solution below, highlighting what doesn't make sense to me:

X: Time until breakdown of part A
Y: Time until Breakdown of part B

Solution says: $Z=\max(X,Y)$ and then goes on to start calculating with
$Cov[X,Z]=E[XZ]-E[X]\cdot E[Z]$.

My first question is, based on the context of the question, why is it that $Z=\max(X,Y)$ is a function that stands in for the time until both parts break down.

The next part I do understand fine, but I'm just including it for context:

After Establishing that $E[X]=20$ and that $F_Z(t)=P(X\leq t)\cdot P(Y\leq t)=\frac{t^2}{800} \implies F'_z(t)=f_z(t) =\frac{t}{800}\implies E[Z]=\int_0^{40} t\cdot \frac{t}{800}dt=\frac{80}{3}$

My second question relates to how this max function is integrated

After having figured out E[Z] and E[X], the question moves on to E[XZ]

Here is what I think I'm understanding ok

$\because E[XY]=\int\int xyf(x)f(y) dydx $, applied to this context, where $Z=h(x,y)=\max(X,Y)$, then by LOTUS, we would have    $\int\int x\cdot h(x,y)\cdot f(x)f(y)dydx$

For $E[XZ]=E[x\cdot h(x,y)]=\int_0^{40}\int_0^{40} x\cdot \max(X,Y) \frac{1}{40}\cdot \frac{1}{40}dy dx$

HERE is where my understanding breaks down entirely, how does the integration of the max function then become
$\int_0^{40}\int_0^{x} x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{1600} dy dx+\int_0^{40}\int_x^{40} xy \cdot \frac{1}{1600} dy dx$

Can someone help me understand how it is that the max function, as an integrand is translated thusly?

Comment: The integration region is a square. Split the square in two triangles. In one $X>Y$ so that max(X,Y)=X. Proceed analogously in the other triangle. Sum the two results.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, the combined life span of both parts is the longer of their two individual life spans, right? They aren't *both* broken until the longer-lived part breaks, that, is, until the maximum of the two life spans has elapsed.

Your second question is easy. In the outer integral, $x$ ranges from $0$ to $40$. In the inner integral, for a fixed $x$ we have that $y$ ranges from $0$ to $40$, which we can regard as $0$ to $x$ and then $x$ to $40$. During the first part ($y$ ranging from $0$ to $x$), $\max(x,y)=x$, and during the second part ($y$ ranging from $x$ to $40$), $\max(x,y)=y$.

Comment: Thank you so much! One further question question about this. After the integral with the max function has been converted into the split integral, on the left side, I understand where $x\cdot x=X^2$ comes from on the left-hand side, or at least I think I do. That is there was in x coefficient right out front of in our $h(x,y)$. But maybe I don't, why are there then two? In any case this leads into my original question: where does the coefficient y come from on the righthand side integral $\int_0^{40}\int_x^{40}xy\frac{1}{1600} dydx$? Thank you again for all of your help!

Comment: If $\max(x,y)=x$, then $x\cdot\max(x,y)=x\cdot x=x^2$, and if $\max(x,y)=y$, then $x\cdot\max(x,y)=x\cdot y=xy$, right?